# Play framework FORM binding to Set instead of List

Tags: java, data-binding, playframework

Is there any way to properly bind to a Set on a form?

I'm doing POJO binding and my controller takes in a User object

```
public static void create(User user)
```

user.java

```
public class User implements Serializable {



    public Long id;

    @Required
    @Email
    public String email;

    public Set<Group> groups;

}
```

Group.java

```
    public class Group implements Serializable {

        public Long id;

        public String name;

    }
```

I can't seem to get my field to bind to groups

i've tried user.groups[].id, user.groups[0].id, user.groups.id.  I can get it to work with a list just fine but when it posts I get a list of N elements with a bunch of null items (one null for each checkbox that was not checked) and I could just create a new list without the nulls but that seems wrong.

**Edit:** User and Group are not meant to be persistent entities, Play is merely acting as a stateless and persistent-less presentation layer for a restful API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new Binder implementation of Play 1.2.4 allows this.

In Play versions earlier to 1.2.4 (released December 02, 2011) you could not bind a set by sending parameters like

```
user.groups[1].id = 1
user.groups[1].name = "name1"
user.groups[3].id = 3
user.groups[3].name = "name3"
user.groups[4].id = 4
user.groups[4].name = "name4"
```

The problem with binding to a List is that you will get a List of length 5 where the value at 0 and 2 is null.

If you still need to use Play version minor than 1.2.4, a workaround for this problem could be using

```
Map<String, Group> groups
```

instead of Set or List. Then you won't get null elements in between and you will get Collection by calling groups.values().

Comment: The values in the square brackets are list indexes and should be consecutive from zero and if they're not Play adds in null values.

Answer (score 0):

First, since `User` and `Group` seems to be Entity, you should extend the `play.db.jpa.Model` class and also define it as an `@Entity`. For example:

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {

    ...

}
```

Thanks to the extension of `Model`, you do not need to define the technical ID (i.e. you can remove the `public Long id`), and you will have a generic DAO for this class (see the [Javadoc](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.1/play/db/jpa/Model.html))

Now, you have to define the groups of `User` like that:

```
@ManyToMany
public Set<Group> groups;
```

Comment: Ok a few things, User and Group are not entities, play is merely acting as a stateless and persistent-less presentation layer for a restful API.  The real issue here and perhaps I didn't highlight that enough is why a FORM cannot bind to a SET but it can to a LIST

Answer (score 0):

I have similiar issue with Play. Play's binding is auto-magic, but sometimes you need to have to workarounds.

You can simply create a setter

```
public void setGroups(List<Group> groups)
```

And internally set the provided groups to your set. It is a bit dirty but will work.

I also recommend you to create a Unit test case to simulate the binding. Create a Map to simulate POST request and bind the map to your object to the Binder. It is much easier than  repeating the process from web-interface, and it forms a regression test and alert you if Play's update break some of the binding behaviors (it happens to me).

Comment: yes this would work but it still doesn't change the fact that you need to name your fields obj.collection[index].prop